# Is there a way to connect a Nodejs backend with AWS Amplify as a Front End

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have made a web Application using React as Front End and Nodejs as  the backend service.
I am trying to host the App on AWS using AWS amplify for Front End and connecting the API service with my already created Nodejs API service.
Is there a way to configure the AWS Amplify with an already existing Nodejs application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already have the nodejs apis deployed somewhere and you are already accessing it in react. If that's the case then you may not need to change anything in react and just add amplify hosting. It should continue to use same api without any issue.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/getting-started.html